# pad rows on a pandas dataframe with zeros till N count

Tags: python, pandas

Iam loading data via pandas read_csv like so:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file_name_item, sep=" ", header=None, usecols=[0,1,2])
```

which looks like so:

```
      0    1    2
0   257  503   48
1   167  258   39
2   172  242   39
3   172  403   81
4   180  228   39
5   183  394  255
6   192  179   15
7   192  347  234
8   192  380  243
9   192  437  135
10  211  358  234
```

I would like to pad this data with zeros till a row count of 256, meaning:

```
      0    1    2
0   157  303   48
1   167  258   39
2   172  242   39
3   172  403   81
4   180  228   39
5   183  394  255
6   192  179   15
7   192  347  234
8   192  380  243
9   192  437  135
10  211  358  234
11  0    0    0
..  ..   ..   ..
256 0    0    0
```

How do I go about doing this? The file could have anything from 1 row to 200 odd rows and I am looking for something generic which pads this dataframe with 0's till 256 rows.

I am quite new to pandas and could not find any function to do this.

Comment: `df.reindex(range(256)).fillna(0)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reindex` with fill_value

```
df_final = data.reindex(range(257), fill_value=0)

Out[1845]:
       0    1   2
0    257  503  48
1    167  258  39
2    172  242  39
3    172  403  81
4    180  228  39
..   ...  ...  ..
252    0    0   0
253    0    0   0
254    0    0   0
255    0    0   0
256    0    0   0

[257 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This works the best, and it is fast as well.

Answer (score 3):

We can do

```
new_df = df.reindex(range(257)).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Comment: one small problem: it changesmy ints to floats... :( any way to have everything as ints?

Comment: Try change downcast